# .css page cutting off footer, wont scroll

Tags: html, css

Whenever I add a decent amount of content to a page, it doesn't scroll and the footer gets cut off. I tried the solutions from the other questions but nothing has worked for me so far. Any suggestions?

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 99%;
}

body {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 99%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    font-size: 8pt; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; 
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
}

/* === Containers === */

#mainContentArea {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
    display: table; 
    height: 100%;  
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    width: 600px;
}

.link,.linkActive {
    width:75px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:24px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background-image:url(tab.gif);
    position:relative; bottom:0px;
}

.link:hover { background-image:url(tab2.gif); }

a { text-decoration:none; }

.link a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#linkGroup {
    margin-right:10px;
    height:40px;
    width:600px;
}

#title {
    width:230px;
    height:40px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.contentTitle {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#213E74;
    font-size:19px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:12px;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    width:573px;
}

.pageContent {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    width:560px;
}


#blueBox {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#E7EDF8;
    width:600px;
    clear:both;
}

#header {
    width:600px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(header.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#footer {
    width:600px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:url(footer.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-align:center;
    padding-right:10px;
    color:#BDCDEC;
}

#footer a {
    font-size:9px;
    color:#BDCDEC;
}

#contentBox { margin-top:25px; }

html, body { text-align: center; }

p {text-align: left;}
```

Comment: Can you add yout HTML into http://jsfiddle.net/xzHfG/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

```
#mainContentArea {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
    display: table; 
    height: 100%;         # set the height to the same as the parent element
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;     # hide (prevent scrolling) content that overflows
    width: 600px;
}
```

Removing the `overflow` directive, or setting it to `auto` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow hidden will hide the scroll bar from your html.

Have you tried to remove the line

```
html {
  overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: The #mainContentArea has overflow:hidden also. Try to remove that.